# How to checkout a forked repository from Bit bucket into an existing workspace?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm completely new to Git and Bit Bucket and I have the basic understanding of it. I have a developer Virtual machine instance which has all the configurations and workspace (which is local repository) related to my project. I was asked to fork the master repository inside bit bucket and get the latest code from remote to workspace. I have created a fork repository on bit bucket and I need suggestions on how to checkout the code to my workspace.

1. Do I need to create a branch for the fork repository and pull the branch to workspace? I see that the clone URL of Master and forked repository are shown as same in bit bucket.
2. My workspace has some of the projects that are already in the workspace. I need to merge all the projects with the latest projects in my forked repository without deleting my existing projects in the workspace. (I don't want to mess up with my configurations). Can anyone explain how to merge?

Answer (score 0):

See if below answers helps you.

1. You can consider the fork as your personal space in the server where you have all the branches and changes automatically synced from the remote repository. Now if you need to make some changes to the files in the repository, follow the below steps. 
   -> Create fork (which you already did) 
   -> Create a clone of the repository 'from the forked area'
   -> either create a local branch or checkout an existing branch
   -> do your changes
   -> commit the changes and push (which will get pushed to your fork)
   -> Issue a Pull request to get it merged with the remote repository

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't want to clone the project because the project is already present in my workspace. When I try to pull or force full, I'm getting an error. What do you suggest?